# I need to get the matched value by comparing the 2 lists in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to compare 2 set of list of strings in JMeter and get the matched values from that list, for that I have used regular expression with Match No. as '-1' to get all the values from the response.

can anyone help me to achieve this using any beanshell scripting or any controller

Thanks in advance.

In the image, I'm getting the list of project codes ,likewise in another response as well. I need to get the project code which is matching in these 2 lists

[JMeter Response Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W203Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables like:

```
foo_1=doorandframe
foo_2=17_08_22
bar_1=08_08_22
bar_2=doorandframe
//etc
```

and would like to get the list of project codes which are present in both extracted lists you can do it using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

```
def firstList = []
1.upto(vars.get('foo_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    firstList.add(vars.get('foo_' + index))
})

def secondList = []
1.upto(vars.get('bar_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    secondList.add(vars.get('bar_' + index))
})

def common = secondList.intersect(firstList)

log.info(common as String)
```

More information: [List.intersect()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#intersect(java.lang.Iterable))

Comment: can you clarify what is foo_matchNr variable in the above script??

In our script im storing the first set of values in the variable V1 and second set in V2.
and im getting the string value in the below format in debug sampler for the defined variables.

V1=NotFOund
V1_1=CuLoTestFR1
V1_10=Loadtest2
V1_10_g=1
V1_10_g0=projectCode:"Loadtest2",
V1_10_g1=Loadtest2
V1_11=Imp_Blaze and so on

Comment: Change `foo` to `V1` and `bar` to `V2` and it should print the common items to [JMeter log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging). I don't know how you're going to be using these common items going forward hence cannot suggest what can be done next, you might want to use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance to store them and refer later on.

Comment: I want to use that common item in another if controller

Comment: as you said i'll try to store it in another variable and use it in futuer. Thanks Dmitri.

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess whether you will have only one match or more and how exactly you're going to use it in the If Controller, I consider this one answered, if you need further help it's better to ask a separate question